# Python Graphics window that updates after every button press

Tags: python

Not sure if this question has been answered but I just didnt see it. I apologize if this is the case.

I am trying to add a graphics window for a script that has already been written. I tried tkinter which is event driven so when i call the mainloop, it wont go beyond that before the window is destroyed. Here is a small example if that helps

```
    import numpy as np
    x = np.array([[5,6,7],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]])
    for i in range(3):
       for j in range(3):
       x[i][j] = some number
       print(x)
```

This will print the x in console. Now I want to use this x to update the graphics window without changing this set of code (which tkinter would do since i would have to use tkinter as a wrapper over the code)

What I was thinking was if there is some way to update this code to

```
    import numpy as np
    class gui():
        def __init__():
            #initializes the window to a state before the update say 
            #Every matrix value is ''
        def update_app(matrix):
            #Takes the matrix and updates the window with the numbers
    x = np.array([[5,6,7],[2,3,4],[4,5,6]])
    for i in range(3):
       for j in range(3):
       x[i][j] = some number
       print(x)
       app.update_app(matrix)
```

Comment: how would the array be used to update the gui?

Comment: would the gui just be a 3x3 grid showing numbers?  And when the matrix is changed then it should update the grid?

Comment: Your title says  "that updates after every button press" but that can't be implemented without making some kind of changes to your for loop, in the simplest case you could turn it into a generator and get the `next` value every time the button is pushed.  (I'd be happy to post an answer showing how to do this if that is indeed what you are looking for)

Comment: yes it would be a 3x3 array that should update when the matrix is changed. Lets say you are using right arrow or left arrow key for a 2048 game. The logic has already been written. What I was trying to do was get the logic ( matrix) into a gui without changing the actual code that was already written.

Comment: I would love to see an example of the generator. However, I more so need a path to understand which GUI module to use to actually get started because I would need a GUI that isnt event driven and can be abstracted enough to be added after (i am a novice in this sense) the whole code is written.

Comment: sorry I didn't post an answer, maybe my [tk_routines library](https://github.com/tadhgmister/tk_routines) would help you translate the code, it is currently badly documented but I made [an example for this case](https://github.com/tadhgmister/tk_routines/blob/master/examples/random3x3grid.py)

Comment: I apologize I should have been more careful about what I say.

Comment: I apologize I should have been more careful about what I say. I can see how the code would work but isnt the GUI still the top level in that code as well? What I was trying to do is simultaneously run two scripts, one GUI which takes an input variable matrix from the none GUI program which has already been written.
The idea was to have a keypress in a game and the GUI as a wrapper around the game which was already coded in. I went around to search for it and found you can use threads but I am not sure how to import the variable from the non GUI code to the GUI code